# Problem form Extracting ProductCardComponent - Cannot read property 'Payload' of undefined

Tags: angular

I need to extract the code of card to separated angular component , The code was work but when I sperated it into another component and reference it to the products component it did't work and gave me this message "Cannot read property 'Payload' of undefined.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
 

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.css']
})
export class ProductCardComponent implements OnInit {

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-input-rename
  @Input('p') product: any = [];
  constructor() { }
 
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" [src]="p.payload.val().imageUrl" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ p.payload.val().title }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ p.payload.val().price | currency:'USD':true}}</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

then I reference it to the products component , If I put this html direcley into the products component it works.

```html
  <div class="col">
      <div class="row"  >
          <ng-container  *ngFor="let p of  filteredProducts ; let i=index" class="container">
            <div class="col">
             <product-card [p]="p"></product-card>
            </div>
            <pre></pre>
            <div *ngIf="(i+1)% 2===0" class="w-100"> </div>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be, DOM Template got rendered before @Input data is received. Its safer to use ternary operator or *ngIf.

```
<div *ngIf="p" class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" [src]="p.payload.val().imageUrl" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ p.payload.val().title }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ p.payload.val().price | currency:'USD':true}}</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---- OR ------

```
<div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" [src]="p?.payload.val().imageUrl" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ p?.payload.val().title }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ p?.payload.val().price | currency:'USD':true}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The Object already assigned and when I print it in console , they back all objects`export class ProductCardComponent implements OnInit {

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-input-rename
  @Input('product') product: any = [];
  constructor() { }
 
  ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.product);
 
  }

}`

Comment: ** when i assigned it , they gave me this error **   _ Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]_   ` <div class="col">
      <div class="row"  >
          <ng-container    *ngFor="let p of  filteredProducts ; let i=index" class="container">
            <product-card [product]="p"></product-card>
     
            <div *ngIf="(i+1)% 2===0" class="w-100"> </div>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
  </div>`